# After a sudden heavy traffic, Tomcat 8 accepted new connections but not responding

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

We are running tomcat 8.0.26 on production environment. After a routine deployment, we were switching traffic to the newly deployed tomcat cluster. The rps on each node was about 800 at that time. Then we found that all nodes were running well except one, which accepted connections but didn't respond. All connections from client are hanging there until timeout. Then I switched off traffic to that node, and captured some status:

1. Not fatal error or exception was found in log.
2. No OOM.
3. There were only a few number of tomcat working thread, all of them were parking there waiting for new tasks.

   ```
   http-nio2-8081-exec-613" #11568 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f710a660800 nid=0xb202 waiting on condition [0x00007f70fee03000]
      java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
       - parking to wait for  <0x00000003c003f008> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   ```
4. Connection could be established when `wget` from localhost, but no response from server.

   ```
   $ wget localhost:8081
   --2015-09-06 19:25:39--  http://localhost:8081/
   Resolving localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1
   Connecting to localhost|::1|:8081... connected.
   HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
   ```
5. `lsof` output:

   ```
   $ lsof -n -i tcp:8081
   COMMAND   PID       USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
   java    34609 web_server   49u  IPv6 2195777660      0t0  TCP *:tproxy (LISTEN)
   wget    41834 web_server    3u  IPv4 2198776305      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:37324->127.0.0.1:tproxy (ESTABLISHED)
   ```
6. After connection established, all of the tomcat working thread were still in parking status.

That is the situation I observed. Could anyone provide me some hint on this issue?

Comment: You may have more success trying this at [sf], where there are a lot of [tomcat related questions](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tomcat).

Comment: Maybe they are all stuck on a lock or something?  A thread-dump might help you locate where the threads are stuck.

Comment: @Gray I guess not. I also checked the status of every thread,  no thread was blocked on something.